# C# - Object value is being lost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to put my object into another by this method:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < NewTblList.Count; i++)
{
    var ItObj = NewTblList[i];

    InternShip It = new InternShip();
    It.Name = NewTblList[i].Name;
    It.Amount = NewTblList[i].Amount;
    It.CreatedDate = NewTblList[i].CreatedDate;
    It.Descr = NewTblList[i].Descr;
    It.Duration = NewTblList[i].Duration;
    It.ExpiryDate = NewTblList[i].ExpiryDate;
    It.StartDate = NewTblList[i].StartDate;

    It = db.Interns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ItObj.ID);
    results = UtilityMethods<InternShip, int>.EditEntity(db, It);
}
```

My problem is that in this line of code:-

```
It = db.Interns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ItObj.ID);
```

My 'It' value is lost. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. PLease HELP!!

Comment: because you are overwriting the `It` obejct with whatever is present in the `Interns` database for `ItObj.ID`.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. Actually I'm passing New values to var ItObj = NewTblList[i]; What will be the solution if I want value for a particular ID?

Comment: If you are trying to update your `Interns` with new values from the `NewTblList`, then move `It = db.Interns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ItObj.ID);` line to the top and remove `InternShip It = new InternShip();`

Comment: Oh Correct!! That was a silly mistake. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Perfectly Working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `It` with whatever is present in the `Interns` database for the Id, `ItObj.ID`.

So you need to change it to:

```
foreach (var internship in NewTblList)
{
    // get the existing internship from the database
    InternShip It = db.Interns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == internship.ID);

    // update the values from your list
    It.Name = internship.Name;
    It.Amount = internship.Amount;
    It.CreatedDate = internship.CreatedDate;
    It.Descr = internship.Descr;
    It.Duration = internship.Duration;
    It.ExpiryDate = internship.ExpiryDate;
    It.StartDate = internship.StartDate;

    results = UtilityMethods<InternShip, int>.EditEntity(db, It);
}
```